# CakePhp extract data from another table for specific user

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakephp2 application where users login based on their credentials on a db. Authentication & Authorizations work fine.

I have a notes table, in which users's notes are stored. Each user can have many notes.

On one page I need to extract all the notes of the logged in user.

I have created a note model :

```
class Note extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Note';

public $belongsTo = 'User';

}
```

and in my user model I have:

```
class User extends AppModel {
public $name = 'User';
public $displayField = 'name';
public $hasMany = 'Note';....
```

In the usercontroller i have created:

```
public function getnotes($id = null) {
$this->User->id = $id;
}
```

but no matter what find statement I run, I can't get only the notes for the specific user. I run debug($id) and I get false on screen, so obviously the current user id is not being recognized.

I have to list all the notes of a user then link to each individual notes page.

Comment: Do you actually pass any ID to the controller? For example: /notes/getnotes/3 ?

Comment: NO actually I don't pass the Uer Id to the getnotes page and prefer not to do so. I'd like to avoid that in order of having a cleaner URL and also for security purposes.

Comment: You do realize what you are saying right? If you don't pass the ID via GET/POST, how do you expect `$this->User->id = $id;` to work? Where does `$id` come from? If it isn't set (via GET/POST) it will always be NULL (because you set it as the default value `($id = null)`)

Comment: Either way you're gonna need to pass an ID parameter somewhere... If you do it via POST then you wont be able to reference specific notes via URL and you will have a Big Problem. I suggest you learn a bit more about how the web works before dabbling with concepts such as MVC..

Comment: I do know how the web works and I'm well aware of passing parameters etc...
What I failed to mention was that since the user is logged in, I expected the $current_user($id) or  $this->Auth->user('id') to be accessible in the controller, so I can use it in the query statement. 
however whatever I try that value is not being registered/passed...

Comment: @user11661286 Next time you should definitely mention such things in your original question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate an AUTH component in cakePHP ...so you will get logged in users ID/Info by auth functions and array like($this->Auth->user('id'))

for auth integration use below link as refence
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

now use this user ID like this in finding records

$this->Note->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Note.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')))